# Is my understanding of how FIELDQUOTE works correct?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am using Azure Synapse and I m querying the following CSV file:

```
1,"A","G"
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

Here is the T-SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'taxi/raw/Sample.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'nyc_taxidata',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIRSTROW=2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        FIELDQUOTE = '"'
    )
    AS [result]
```

Here is the output:

```
C1   C2   C3
1    A    G
2    B    H
3    C    I
4    D    J
5    E,F  K
```

I then altered the CSV file to add a colon just before the letter G as so:

```
1,"A",:"G"
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

I get:

```
C1   C2   C3
1    A    :"G"
2    B    H
3    C    I
4    D    J
5    E,F  K
```

This lead me to make the following conclusions about FIELDQUOTE:

- The query as a whole scans each row, character by character looking for either a FIELDQUOTE or a FIELDTERMINATOR. If it finds a FIELDQUOTE first then it ignores any FIELDTERMINATORS until it finds another FIELDQUOTE (I'm basing this on the last row).
- The FIELDQUOTE should have a FIELDTERMINATOR immediately before it in order for the FIELDQUOTE to work as expected (I'm basing this on the first row of the second example).

I could be well off the mark here but can anyone give me some feedback on this?.

When I tried running the query above on this CSV:

```
1,"A"":",G
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

It returned the following:

```
 C1   C2  C3
1    A":  G
2    B    H
3    C    I
4    D    J
5    E,F  K
```

So I tried with this CSV:

```
Number,Letter
1,"A""":",G
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

However I got the following error:

```
Error handling external file: 'Unexpected token ':' at [byte: 22]. Expecting tokens ',', ' ', or '"'. '. File/External table name: 'taxi/raw/Sample.csv'.
```

I then tried the CSV:

```
Number,Letter
1,"A":",G
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

And I got the following:

```
Error handling external file: 'Unexpected token ':' at [byte: 20]. Expecting tokens ',', ' ', or '"'. '. File/External table name: 'taxi/raw/Sample.csv'.
```

Lastly, I tried this CSV:

```
Number,Letter
1,"A":",G
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

I got the following error:

```
Error handling external file: 'Unexpected token ':' at [byte: 20]. Expecting tokens ',', ' ', or '"'. '. File/External table name: 'taxi/raw/Sample.csv'.
```

The strangest one was when I tried running:

```
Number,Letter
1,"A""",G
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

I got:

```
 C1   C2        C3
1    A"",G2,B"  H
3    C          I
4    D          J
5    E,F        K
```

Comment: I'm confused on your second example. Are you saying you change the CSV file's first row to be: `1,A,:G` and `OPENROWSET()` bring that in as `:'G'`. That seems very odd behavior. FWIW, I believe your first conclusion is accurate. Specifying the character for string encapsulation or `FIELDQUOTE` in this dialect of csv parser, acts exactly as you describe. It allows row delimiters/terminators, field delimiters/terminators, and even the character used for string encapsulation itself (in most parsers when specifying an escape character) to exist in the string literal for that field.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I'm partially on the right track. Regarding the second example, I've made some changes to the question to make it clearer. I had also made a slight typo with the :'G' which I have now corrected.

Comment: That's helpful clarification. Working exactly as I would expect it to! :) I moved my comment to an answer and added on for the second conclusion. I think your assumptions/conclusions are right on. The conclusion also extends to nearly every other CSV parser I've used (thinking python's pandas.read_csv() and similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *"The query as a whole scans each row, character by character looking for either a FIELDQUOTE or a FIELDTERMINATOR. If it finds a FIELDQUOTE first then it ignores any FIELDTERMINATORS until it finds another FIELDQUOTE (I'm basing this on the last row)."*

   From my comment: I believe your first conclusion is accurate. Specifying the character for string encapsulation or `FIELDQUOTE` in this dialect of csv parser, acts exactly as you describe. It allows row delimiters/terminators, field delimiters/terminators, and even the character used for string encapsulation itself (in most parsers when specifying an escape character) to exist in the string literal for that field.

   Oddly, I don't think that `OPENROWSET()` allows for specifying an escape character, so I'm not sure how you would get a double quote character into your field/string-literal if it's encapsulated. But that's not part of your question just an observation reading through the documentation. I would be curious what `OPENROWSET()` would do with `1,"A"":",G` or `1,"A":",G`
2. *"The FIELDQUOTE should have a FIELDTERMINATOR immediately before it in order for the FIELDQUOTE to work as expected (I'm basing this on the first row of the second example)."*

   Yes. I believe this is true as well and is true with any CSV parser I've ever used. The string encapsulation character must follow either row or field terminator/delimiter and must be followed by the row or field terminator/delimiter for it to be recognized as an encapsulated string (or not error). I would be curious what `OPENROWSET()` would do with `1,"A":,G`.

Comment: I tried to run the query using 1,"A"":",G and 1,"A":",G as the first row. I've included the answers in the question section as it's much clearer to illustrate and read it. I was not expecting an error. Do you think it throws the second conclusion I made into question?.

Comment: The last CSV I ran threw me off. I was not expecting that!. From what I can observe is that directly after a FIELDQUOTE and directly before a FIELDQUOTE there must be a FIELDTERMINATOR.. The error I received was because SQL was anticipating a comma as that was set as the FIELDTERMINATOR. This is just me thinking out loud. Do you think that this is a reasonable conclusion to make?.

Comment: That's fun :) The first two errors are totally what I would expect. That last one just happens to work out. Even though you can't specify an escape character when using string encapsulation, it is clearly defaulting to `"`. So `"This is a single ""field"""` is perfectly legal and will result in the string `This is a single "field"`. The reason that the last test doesn't error is because the first and second records just happen to make exactly 3 fields, which it's expecting.

Comment: Actually I take that back. That last one is strange as hell. It's escaping using the `"` character, totally expected, but those last two single `"` characters around the `B` are being interpreted as literal... I can't explain that one.  :)

Comment: Yes it was enjoyable to run these tests. Hopefully we'll get the answer to the last one some day. Thanks for the help. One final question, would you say that my observation: "directly after a FIELDQUOTE and directly before a FIELDQUOTE there must be a FIELDTERMINATOR" is a valid statement?.

Comment: I think that is a fair statement. That last test suggests that maybe `OPENROWSET` will make an attempt at figuring out what was meant by the creator of the CSV, so there is likely a small amount of wiggle room there.