# Escape characters in .csv for Azure Synapse seems to dissapear?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-synapse, openrowset

I have .csv file that looks like this:

```
"ID", "Name", "Extra Info"
"1", "John", "{\"Event\": \"Click\", \"Button Name\": \"Accept\"}
"2", "Adam", "{\"Event\": \"Click\", \"Button Name\": \"Accept\"}
```

I'm trying to load this file using this code in Synapse:

```
SELECT
    TOP 2 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://[MY STORAGE ACCOUNT].dfs.core.windows.net/[FILE PATH]/[...]/*.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) 
AS [result]
```

Expecting this result:

| ID | Name | Extra Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | {"Event": "Click", "Button Name": "Accept"} |
| 2 | Adam | {"Event": "Click", "Button Name": "Accept"} |

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error handling external file: 'Unexpected token 'Event\' at [byte: XXX]. 
Expecting tokens ',', ' ', or '"'. '. 
File/External table name: 'https://[MY STORAGE ACCOUNT].dfs.core.windows.net/[FILE PATH]/[...]/[SPECIFIC FILE NAME].csv'.
```

It looks like it's ignoring the first quote (") and Escape character in the Extra Info column? Leading to it think that \Event\ is some special token?

I just don't understand why or what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer based on this post and some of the Azure documentation:

- How Field Quote works: [Is my understanding of how FIELDQUOTE works correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73404603/is-my-understanding-of-how-fieldquote-works-correct)
- Escaping Quotes in the Azure Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-single-csv-file#escape-quoting-characters

It seems that the only valid way to escape Quotes is by using double quotes.

This means my .csv should be formatted like this:

```
"ID", "Name", "Extra Info"
"1", "John", "{""Event"": ""Click"", ""Button Name"": ""Accept""}
"2", "Adam", "{""Event"": ""Click"", ""Button Name"": ""Accept""}
```

Instead of the original (which uses ):

```
"ID", "Name", "Extra Info"
"1", "John", "{\"Event\": \"Click\", \"Button Name\": \"Accept\"}
"2", "Adam", "{\"Event\": \"Click\", \"Button Name\": \"Accept\"}
```

Unfortunately I don't see a way around this other than BULK editing all my .csv files...